# What is the relationship between the vortex and the edge tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I work with the `MySQL` database and I have 2 tables namely `vortex` and the `edge`. I provided it below,

[image]

Is this `one-to-many` relationship exists between the tables ? Some explanation will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `one-to-many` relationships because each `vertex` can be the source or the destination of many edges, but each `edge` can only have one source and one destination.

Speaking in terms of rows in the tables, you will have each vertex `id` appearing only once in the vertex table, but potentially more than once in the `vertex_src_id` and in the `vertex_dst_id` columns of the edges table.

Answer (score 0):

You have two relation between these tables  both one-to-many (one to (one or many ) )

one is based

```
vertex_src_id
```

and the second on

```
vertex_dst_id
```

Comment: I haven't get your answer, sorry. Some explanation will be helpful.